# Getting different gray-level values from a matrix (Gray-level image)

Tags: matlab, matrix, computer-vision

I have this matrix:

```
image= [200 200 200 200 200 200 200; 
        200 180 180 180 180 180 200;
        200 180 120 150 120 180 200;
        200 180 150  40 150 180 200;
        200 180 120 150 120 180 200;
        200 180 180 180 180 180 200;
        200 200 200 200 200 200 200];
```

I want to get the different gray-values and put them in an array, so my array will look like this:

```
 Array= [40 120 150 180 200];
```

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Using loops if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unique` function does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks,but if i want to use loops how can i achieve the same thing?

Comment: I don't see any problem with loops. Please explain your question.

Comment: Can you get to the same result without using the "unique" function? just by using some loops?

Comment: I don't see any advantage, what is the purpose??

Comment: Definitively there is no advantage since the "unique" function is doing it great, but since i have similar other programs i want to make, it will be great if i saw how someone handles such a problem and solve it using loops, so that i can tackle similar cases better.